# How to create auto collapsed all list item in Jquery nestable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-nestable

I'm using jQuery plugin Nestable for menus editor. I want all menu items to auto collapse, but also to expand when a user clicks on each expandable icon.

Here is jQuery Nestable plugin.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#product_list").nestable({
      maxDepth: 10,
      collapsedClass:'dd-collapsed',
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since there isn't much option available in this `plugin` what you can do is manually collapse once the `nestable` has been created as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#product_list").nestable({
      maxDepth: 10,
      collapsedClass:'dd-collapsed',
   }).nestable('collapseAll');//Add this line
   //$("#product_list").nestable('collapseAll') //Or this
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3r3qgv7w/)** with expanded view without collapsing on load
and

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3r3qgv7w/1/)** with collapsed view on load

Comment: Great, this helped me a lot. Any chance a similar logic could be used to 'Expand All' ?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the auto-collapse which Guruprasad had a good answer for, here is a simple way to remove all collapsed, equivalent to what your 'Collapse All' button would do.

```
$(".dd-collapsed").removeClass("dd-collapsed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function:

```
$('.dd').nestable('collapseAll');
```