# collapse and expand nestable list by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-nestable

I am using the plugin nestable (jquery) to display few nestable lists on the same page. 
By default all the lists are expanded.
I have found this solution to collapse all the lists [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518825/how-to-create-auto-collapsed-all-list-item-in-jquery-nestable)

my question is how can I chose the state of the lists independently(some default expanded and the other collapsed).?

Comment: share your code please

Comment: I generate the code in the backend using PHP , In the Front end I call  App.uiNestableLists();

Answer (score 0):

In the back end , I add a class ('expandmenu') to the item that I want it to be expanded.

Then I add this in the front-end:

```
 $(".expandmenu [data-action]").each(function () {

                                        if($(this).html()=="Expand"){
                                          $(this).click();  
                                        }

                                        });
```